# How can I store an integer number that's greater than 2147483647 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

From what I understand integers range from

```
 -2147483648 through 2147483647
```

I am confused because I noticed some references to big int in javascript. Can someone explain how I can store an integer number larger than 2147483647?

Comment: Javascript will not handle integers with more precision than that by itself.  You will have to use some sort of library that creates its own numeric format and offers its own operators for it.

Comment: You can store integers larger than that, just not all of them

Comment: Relevant: [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin)

Answer (score 1):

To get past JavaScript's internal numeric limits, use something like a [bignum library](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) (Just a random one I found, research for a good library left as an exercise to OP).

Answer (score 1):

[BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) is an arbitrary-length integer library for Javascript, allowing arithmetic operations on integers of unlimited size, notwithstanding memory and time limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing the number, you can handle integers up to +/- (2^53)-1 or `9007199254740991`.

While not all browsers support `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` yet, you can calculate it with:

```
Math.pow(2, 53) - 1
```

Note: This works when in pure math functions, but many bitwise operations are limited to 16 bit integers, as well as the index in arrays.

More details can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways we can store big int.

```
const bigIntVal=123243435454656565657575n;
```

or

```
const bigIntVal=BigInt("123243435454656565657575");
```